# Add a div to replace Video after Video Plays Through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

How can I code a video; that will play through; and after it runs to the end. The video is then replaced with a **div** (Specifically within that #div an animated gif).

But in anycase; how could I write this?

Something like; *(But I don't want a new Window / URL; but a div to replace inline)*

```
$oVideo.bind('ended', function() {
window.location = 'http://coolurl.com';
$oVideo[0].pause();
$oPause.hide();
$oPlay.css('display', 'block');
});
```

**Basically; Video plays through > it ends > Video disappears > A div replaces it** (#div with an animated gif in it).

Comment: I'm having some trouble trying to understand what you are asking for. Do you need to find a method to determine when the video has ended? or are you asking for the code to show this div with the animated gif after the video has ended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so, if I understand correctly, you are looking to have a video play then the video disappear and be replaced with a div containing some arbitrary content.

in regular HTML/JS/CSS something like this does what you're asking for. Should be fairly easy to convert to jQuery (rather than the window.location you're setting in the question simply set the style on the video to display:none and the div you want to show to display:block)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="vidBox" id="box">
    <video class="vid" poster="http://www.rufan-redi.com/assets/lizard_goldeye.jpg" preload="metadata" controls="true" id="video1" height="240" width="360">
        <source src="http://jcath-drg.s3.amazonaws.com/BigBuck.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="other" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px; background-color:#f0f0f0">
        This appears after the video ends
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var vid=document.getElementById('video1');
    vid.addEventListener("ended", hideVideo, false);

    function hideVideo() {
        var vid=document.getElementById('video1');
        var other=document.getElementById('other');
        vid.removeEventListener("ended", hideVideo, false);
        vid.style.display='none';
        other.style.display='block';
    }
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```