# HTML5 video background and transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am making a website for a friend of mine and he wants a really complicated one. Between the menupoints there are videos and the content is displayed on the last frame. So I thought I could use the videos (about 2 seconds long) as a background and fade the content in after two seconds. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

what I'd do is have the content as a hidden div. When you play the video attach an onended event to it and use that to hide the video element and reveal the content - that way they always stay in sync - for instance see something like this [Add a div to replace Video after Video Plays Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382551/add-a-div-to-replace-video-after-video-plays-through/14387179#14387179)